# Image tracing path with mouse instead of just moving with the mouse

Tags: python

When I drag the mouse over the image, the image traces a path with the mouse instead of moving. See the screenshot for an example of this behavior:

[image: screenshot]

Here is the code:

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.display.init()
clock=pygame.time.Clock()

canvas=pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("hy")

color=(255,0,0)

canvas.fill(color)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)
pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.diamond)

img=pygame.image.load("maryo.png")



while True:
    x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()


for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==KEYDOWN:
        if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

canvas.blit(img,(x,y))

clock.tick(60)   

pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Hi there. Please don't ask for urgent treatment on Stack Overflow - questions here are of equal importance, and chat of this kind just becomes noise that needs to be edited out in the future.

Comment: Does it work now? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don´t want a tracing path, **you need to clear the screen before you blit the `img`-surface onto a new position** in your main game loop.

This can be done by calling the [`fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) method of the main screen object `canvas`:

```
while True:
    x,y=pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        canvas.fill(color) #clear the screen
        canvas.blit(img,(x,y)) #blit img onto screen

        clock.tick(60)   

        pygame.display.update()
```